# SQL count distinct minimums of grouped values

Tags: sql, postgresql

How can I count how many times each minimum exists?

I've included example dataset in following link:
https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/nUJdzj3ETXb8knMfeqYtRw/0

for example there are six 1's in the table, however only four of them are minimums for corresponding name

desired output would be

| minimum | count |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 2 |
| 1 | 4 |
| 2 | 1 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use group by minimum to get that

```
select minimum, count(minimum) from (
SELECT name, MIN(id) minimum FROM testdb  
GROUP BY (name))t
group by minimum
order by minimum
```

db-fiddle link:

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/nUJdzj3ETXb8knMfeqYtRw/0#&togetherjs=t2hru6IGtw

**Output:**

| minimum | count |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 2 |
| 1 | 4 |
| 2 | 1 |

Answer (score 0):

you can try using corelated subquery

-- minimum for every person

```
SELECT  id,count(*)
FROM testdb  t1
where id=(select min(id) from testdb t2 where t1.name=t2.name)
GROUP BY id
```

[DEMO](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/nUJdzj3ETXb8knMfeqYtRw/0)

Answer (score 0):

you can use `PARTITION BY` clause, as follows:

```
SELECT distinct MIN(id) as minimum, count(name) over (partition by min(id))
FROM testdb
group by name
order by minimum
```